# find type of sql statement using php and no Regex

Tags: php, mysqli

I am wondering
if we can know..
what type of query is executed in php script.
`DML` or `DDL` statement
Can know that.. using php..
with out Regex

### Below is the query i executed

```
$queryOne = "SELECT * FROM employees";

// using php script
$queryOne is DML


$queryTwo = "DROP table employees";

//using php script
$queryTwo is DDL
```

Comment: Read the first word of the query, and define whether it is DML or DDL.

Comment: Why one would need that?

Comment: @str I dont want it in Regex

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am wondering.

Comment: @Rafee Did I mention RegEx? No.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions out of idle curiosity are no welcome on this site.

Comment: @YourCommonSense [citation needed]. (Of course they are welcome, use your common sense.)

Comment: I wish to, but site rules state the contrary. Care to read them?

Comment: I can't believe so many people didn't read them. Okay, for all you who never done it before: `Focus on questions about an` **actual problem** `you have faced` (none provided). `Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.` (Even when asked for the latter explicitly, the OP failed to provide an required info)

Comment: And yes, my common sense smells some false assumption led to this XY problem. Especially with limitation ("with out Regex") provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classically, the DML statements are:

```
SELECT
INSERT
DELETE
UPDATE
MERGE (newcomer on the block)
```

Anything else is DDL - according to some sets of definitions.

Some of the 'other statements' are more like 'session control' statements; not really DML, not really DDL.

If you wish to detect these statements, you can either prepare (and describe) the statement and look at the returned information to diagnose whether it is one of the DML statements listed above, or you can scan for these keywords as the first non-comment words in the statement. This covers the vast majority of practical cases. What you do if you have a single string with multiple statements (possibly of different types) in them is a decision you'll have to make on your own. Not all DBMS allow that anyway.

or use regex.

Comment: I cant believe, depending upon `regex`

Comment: How come SELECT is a DML statement?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ever seen `SELECT ... INTO`? :)